# MySQL: Performing Updates on a Large Table with Indices

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-indexes, database-optimization

Evening,

I have a large but simple table with nearly 30 million rows. The table has an index for most columns. It's taking a long time to perform any updates on it and I was wondering wheter it would be a good idea to delete the indices and re-built them once I have finished with my changes to the table?

The reason I ask is because I have read some posts on here where people haven't been able to re-build an index on a large table. However, I don't see why that should be as I can import this table from a 2.2GB text file in 20 minutes.

The table is comprised of a few small ints and varchars.

The update queries I ran were like:

```
UPDATE census SET rCo = 11470 WHERE rCo = 'Zet';
```

They weren't too slow, but I am currently changing one of the fields from varchar(4) to varchar(8) and it's taking a very long time.

I ran the update query from the command line (Linux).

Comment: Please post your update query. It could just be an underperforming query.

Comment: I've added det.s on the query and where they were run from.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should keep the index since you are using it in the where clause.

On the other hand, I'm pretty sure you should rather build up a brand new table:

```
CREATE TABLE census_2 (...) 
SELECT ..., IF(rCo = 'Zet', 11470, rCo) FROM census
```

and then drop the old one, + recreate the indexes on the new one AFTERWARDS.

Comment: I've got a lot of queries to run on the table to update it. I've built it from an obsolete 15-year-old data format called FolioViews. As you can guess it is a complete mess>

Anyway. I restarted my computer and that seems to have done the trick. It must have gotten itself in a bad place after 6 hours of data processing and data inserts :)

Thanks for your time.